# Get BLOB image from mysql database via JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, blob

I have an image stored as BLOB in my MySQL database. I am returning the image back to the android app via PHP JSON array like this: `$row_array['image'] = base64_encode($row['image']);`
Now I am getting the value in android like this `String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);` where c is a JSON Object. Then I tried decoding it

```
byte[] b = Base64.decode(image, 0);

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
```

But this just gives me a null pointer exception and crashes. What am I doing wrong here?

Logcat:

```
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925):    at com.example.shareity.ListNew$JSONParse.onPostExecute(ListNew.java:254)
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925):    at com.example.shareity.ListNew$JSONParse.onPostExecute(ListNew.java:1)
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-16 15:40:47.469: E/AndroidRuntime(30925):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the exception. Is it on Base64.decode (there is no data in image) or in BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (the data could not be properly base64 decoded)?

Comment: It just says NullPointerException as blah blah @JPMoresmau

Comment: @YohanBlake it might not look like anything more than "blah blah" to you, but your answer might be inside that "blah blah". If you post the exception output, someone might be able to help you find an answer from it.

Comment: @DanGetz I have added the logcat

Comment: Ok, now you can see in the 3rd line of the logcat, that it crashes when, on line 254 of `ListNew.java`, you try to use a value which is `null`. That might be a clue as to what's going on. Is that line one of the lines of code you already posted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose the `event` is the table name , `image` is the column name that holds the `BLOB` Image and `user_id` is the id of the user/row . To extract the image from the BLOB, You should create an EXTRA PHP File. which would like something like this.

**get_image.php**

```
<?php 
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("shareity",$db) or die(mysql_error()); 
$userId = $_GET['eid']; 
$query = "SELECT image FROM event WHERE eid='$userId'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
$photo = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg'); 
echo $photo['image']; 
?>
```

Now,`get_image.php` is like an image. if you pass a `user_id` through GET to the `get_image.php` will throw the `user_image`.

So when ever you encode the json from server side,add a field which append the user id with the `get_image.php` like this

```
{
 'ID':1,
 'userName':'John',
 'image_url':'http://your-host-name/get_image.php?ID=1'
}
```

So from the Android, you can decode the image like this

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://your-host-name/get_image.php?ID=1");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Log exception
    return null;
}
```

**More clarification can be fnd [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78005/discussion-between-shifar-shifz-and-yohan-blake)**

Comment: can you please tell me what to include in my original php file in order to get the JSON result `{
    "image_url":"http://example.com/myImageDecoder.php?id=1"
}`?

Comment: it has to be `$row_array['image'] = something ;` Can you please tell me what to add there?

Comment: Yeah, `$con` holds the db connection.Let me ask you some question. what is the `table name and column name` which holds the image as BLOB data-type ?

Comment: Table name is event. Column name is image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78005/discussion-between-shifar-shifz-and-yohan-blake).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("shareity",$db) or die(mysql_error()); 
$userId = $_GET['eid']; 
$query = "SELECT image FROM event WHERE eid='$userId'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
$photo = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg'); 
echo $photo['image']; 
?>
```